# How to adjust the Beamer default font size more finely?

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I can adjust the default font size for a Beamer presentation using any of these options:

```
\documentclass[pdf,12pt]{beamer} % very small
\documentclass[pdf,14pt]{beamer} % small
\documentclass[pdf,20pt]{beamer} % very large
```

Values between `14pt` and `20pt` give the same result as `12pt`, but I think the optimal font size lies somewhere between. How can I adjust the font size to something like `18pt`?

Comment: [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) allows for a `17pt` font size option...

Comment: Oh. I only tried 16pt and 18pt. 17, such an odd number. I'd still like to know how to choose other sizes.

Comment: There is no easy way: The list of font size options in beamer is hard coded. If you want other font sizes you should copy the definitions from e.g. size17.clo to your preamble, change `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand` and then adjust the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easy way: The list of font size options in beamer is hard coded. If you want other font sizes you should copy the definitions from e.g. `size17.clo` to your preamble, change `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand` and then adjust the values.